# HTML CSS gradient with color position using browser's afterprocess variables

Tags: html, css, variables, gradient

I'm trying to make a background gradient. My website will be with width limited in `1024px`, so I'd want a horizontal gradient that goes fine for every browser/screen resolution, like this:

> Black -- Lightgray(where the page starts) -- Lightgray(where the page ends) -- Black.

If it's possible, I'd also want to know how to obtain the variables that the browsers create after processing the site, like auto-margin value, to set the `"lightgray color stop"` position. This way there won't be a screen waste with only one color and a relatively small page into big resolutions. Also, I still don't know how to put variables into a CSS `"value"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean entirely, but if I were trying for that effect, I would build a gradient using a tool like this [css gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). It uses percentages, so the color stop won't be affected by changes in pixel values ... for example, the gradient could always end at 50% of the page height, no matter what.

Hopefully this answers your question or puts you in the right direction!

Comment: I don't think this could help me. my page will have 1024px in width, and is centered. I meant to have a lightgray to black gradient on each side. I'm afraid the "CSS Gradient Generator" you said works with percentages of the browser's window, so I can't use this. I meant to use the browser's variables (like the auto-margin values) to set the "color stops" position.

Comment: Sounds like what you want might be more like a `box-shadow` on the main content area. You might have to provide more info, like a photoshop mockup that shows the desired effect.

Comment: This also won't work. a box-shadow requires a value for its width, and till now I've found no way to get the "auto-margin" variables that are created when you load the page/change the browser's window size.

Comment: You can get the `element.offsetLeft` value with javascript to see how far the element is from the left of the browser window. The right would be the same if the element was centered.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. If it doesn't works I'll come back here for more help.

Comment: Hello again. I managed to create a background gradient using percentages, but I still don't know how to put javascript variables into those percentages. You can access my website (kdasws.freeoda.com) and see the resources tab. It shows an error in the javascript, saying that it can't identify: offsetWidth.
Also, I don't know in what tag to put the id="bstyle" so that the code works. As you can see, the last part of the javascript doesn't work.